# Angular: How to validate a date input based on selection of another date input

Tags: angular, validation

I have two input date fields i.e Invoice Date and Invoice Due Date. Using Angular how can i make the Invoice Due Date not less than the Invoice Date?

I am new to Angular, so I really don't know how to proceed.

```
   <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>Invoice Date</label><br>
                <input type="date" [disabled]="true" name="invoicedate" class="form-control readOnly-date" [(ngModel)]="invoice.invoiceDate" *ngIf="!invoice.financialPeriodId">
                <input type="date" name="invoicedate" min="{{startDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" max="{{endDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="invoice.invoiceDate" *ngIf="invoice.financialPeriodId">
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>Due Date</label><br>
                <input type="date" name="dueDate" class="form-control readOnly-date" [(ngModel)]="invoice.invoiceDueDate" *ngIf="!invoice.invoiceDate">
                <input type="date" name="dueDate" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="invoice.invoiceDueDate" *ngIf="invoice.invoiceDate">
            </div>
```

Depending on the value for the Invoice Date, the Invoice Due Date should not be less than the Invoice Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `[min]="invoice.invoiceDate"` like this:

```
<input type="date" name="dueDate" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="invoice.invoiceDueDate" *ngIf="invoice.invoiceDate" [min]="invoice.invoiceDate">
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvrkd5?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Please upvote and accept this answer if this helped :)